# What did Guido say to Chick's pit crew in Italian?

Tags: dialogue, cars

*Cars* ends with McQueen at the Los Angeles International race track doing his final race for the Piston Cup. When he his doing this, his Radiator Spring friends like Doc Hudson, Luigi, Ramone, Guido, came to the pit and helped him. When Chick's pit crew see Guido and insult him, Guido shouts at Chick's pit crew in Italian.

Does anyone know what Guido said to Chick's pit crew in Italian?

Answer (score 12):

A transcipt reads...

> Con chi credi di parlare?
>
> Ma, con chi stai parlando?
>
> <sup>[source](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=cars)</sup>

Which Google Translate tells me is:

> Who do you think you're talking to?
>
> But, who are you talking to?

---

There's a possiblity suggested by a commenter that this might have been a De Niro
(*Taxi Driver*) take-off.

That may have been the intention - Google Translate turns "You talkin' to me? to *"Stai parlando a me?"*.

I'm not an italian speaker so if this was the intention I'm inclined to think that someone would have done a better job of the translation.

Comment: How very Robert De Niro of him :)

Comment: That may have been the intention -  Google Translate turns "You talkin' to me? to  *"Stai parlando a me?"*